# Is it a good idea to store multiple values as SharedPreference?

Tags: android, local-storage, android-sharedpreferences

In my android app I have about 100 places (maximum will be 200). I want to allow the user to mark each place as visited and store this selection.

So the user can mark/unmark that he already visited some places/cities.

Is it a good idea if I store the values as SharedPreference?

My code:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putString("London", "1");
editor.commit();
```

and next time when user marks another place then:

```
editor.putString("Paris", "1");
```

I am asking due to amount of possible places to be stored there, which will be maximum 200 in my case. I am usually using this kind of storage just to store some settings or so, but I think this is an easy way to store the values in my case too, I don't want to use database or anything similar for storage.

Comment: What happens if you want to show all "visited" places to the user? You may want to use `Sqlite ` earlier. You will not limit yourself with `SharedPreferences` capabilities but you will have more flexibility. SharedPreferences are generally used to store simple settings key/value and other primitive datas to easy access.

Comment: *I don't want to use database or anything similar for storage.* - you think you don't, but you do

Comment: Don't be afraid of using SQLite. There are great libraries like Room https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/

Comment: @wotan you don't want use any database like SQLite and parse.com

Comment: Ozgur - I'll just simple check if that place is stored in SharedPreferences in 'for' cycle for example, when I want to show all visited places. The places are loaded from JSON, and when I parse it, I can immediately check, if the name is stored as SharedPreference. But I will try to study something about the SQL lite as more of you suggested

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether this is a good idea or not depends on your requirements and expectations. If you store the data like this, it will work for sure, but, there will be some limitations:

- It might be complicated to show a list of places to the user. If you store some other data to shared preferences you will need a way to distinguish places from other data. In this case you'll probably need to add a prefix to all your keys, such as "place_London", "place_Paris", etc.
- You are relying on English key names so you might have issues with localization if you support other languages
- It will be much harder to support versioning and scalability. E.g. if later you have an entity called "Place" and it has more information than just a name with a flag, then it will be much harder to keep it in shared preferences. E.g. if at some point you want to add a corresponding country name to all places, what do you do?

I think in this scenario you actually *DO* want to use database. It will pay off.

Comment: I learned somethng about SQLite, and I didn't realize that can be use as a local database! In this case I will use SQLite for my storage. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

SharedPreferences is a key/value way to save data. I think it is not appropriate to save large amount of structured data as you have to define a key for each value you have.

Using SQLite might be a better option for your case.

Answer (score 0):

You should switch to a more reliable way of storing data in storage instead of using SharedPreferences.

Sqlite is good option but if you don't like to write `SQL Queries` and want a solution where you want to store data in your storage, `Realm` is an amazing alternative.

Although before implementing please read more on the pros and cons of using realm. You can read more about Realm here :-

[realm.io](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/)

[Realm vs Room vs ObjectBox](https://notes.devlabs.bg/realm-objectbox-or-room-which-one-is-for-you-3a552234fd6e)